# How to create an registration form in django and create an qr code for the given data also store data in mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, mysql-python

create an platform with Django that gets input from the user about their name, states and cities in India and create QR code for it , also the data needs to be stored in Mysql database.
The states and cities should be in dependent dropdown.

If anyone can create this project, please send the code to me via email.

Thanks for accepting!